# Sill plates (thresholds) before floor tiles or otherwise?

Tags: flooring, tile

The contractor wants to install the granite sill plates now and later have the tiles installed. I heard from one granite fellow that the sill plates should be last.

Is there any advantage for going one route or another? I would like to have the sills already installed and be done with it, but I also don't want gaps between the sill and the tile.

Comment: Granite sill plate? Do you mean a tile base?

Comment: I might be using the wrong word. I mean the pieces of granite that goes between different floors and below doorways. In Brazil that I'd very common : http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_lX6_MZ6kq0I/TUra7YgAfJI/AAAAAAAAANw/LBOkUn_mmSE/s1600/IMG_1035.jpg

Comment: Ahha. I'd call that a threshold but every area had its own lingo.

Comment: I might me using the wrong word, i thought of window sill, then i went to door sill and pictured that it might also be called sill.

Comment: No worries. Terminology is always a hurdle even between tradesman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing the thresholds first.  These are very prominent and you want the things that stand out looking the best.  In a doorway if you do threshold first then it is a rectangle fitting doorway.  If you do the threshold last, than who knows - this would be up to how square your room is and how well you aligned your tiles.

**Added:** Also when cutting or placing threshold you want to align it up with the wall in the room you will tile.  So you have threshold, grout, then first tile row.  You shouldn't have to cut the first row of tile to adjust for the threshold - they should flow over threshold.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the general process it's acceptable to do it threshold(sill plate) first but there may be specifics to the situation that we're not aware of. Contractors are primarily concerned with pushing the project along to keep pace, but occasionally to do that you have to do things out of sequence. An example would be, if the threshold is available but the tile isn't in yet, a contractor would be tempted to set the thresholds first. This might make it look like progress is being made but it could ultimately make your tile guys job a lot more difficult. If the guy contracted to do the tile work wants to do it a particular way, I would trust his/her judgement unless the contractor can produce a very compelling reason not to. In the end (however they do it) if the finished product isn't satisfactory it's on them to make it right.

Comment: The contractor really wants to push the threshold now because he will be doing the screed layer over the concrete base. He is not the one who will do the tiles (i think that i will do that, as the tile workers around here aren't reliable).

Comment: Hmm, that does change things. I'll scratch my head and get back to you.

Comment: I have gone round and round on this and I just can't in good conscience advise you one way or the other without being intimately involved in the project. There's just too many variables. All I can say is I can't think of anything specifically wrong with setting your thresholds first.